# Issue with screen overeflow

Tags: display, display-resolution, screen

I have issue with screen overflow. I have notebook and 2 additional monitors. On ma left monitor my screen overflows my resolution. Any tips?

[image: Screen overflow]

Comment: Not really a monitor but a TV, right? You have 2 options: 1. (preferable) Adjust it in the TV's menus and/or remote (read your user's manual) 2. open screen settings and enable "adjust for TV" (be aware this is a very new feature and issues have been reported),

Comment: No it is a monitor not tv